# Настройка debugging deno в docker

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, отладка

При текущей настройке debugger, код приложения запускается и исполняется сразу после запуска  докера. То есть break point не отрабатывают. Вопрос что нужно донастроить, чтобы была возможность отлаживать приложение в докере также, как в случае отладки с локального компьютера?

Пример кода

```
console.log("Hello, World!");
console.log("Hello, World2!");
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Deno Docker",
            "port": 9229,
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "remoteRoot": "/app"
        }
    ]
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM denoland/deno

EXPOSE 8000

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

RUN deno cache main.ts

CMD ["run", "--allow-net", "--inspect=0.0.0.0:9229", "main.ts"]
```

dockerp-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: deno-container
    image: deno-image
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
      - 127.0.0.1:9229:9229
```

Answer (score 0):

Обновил Dockerfile заменил `--inspect` на `--inspect-brk` (if the program shouldn't start running, but must wait for the debugger to attach)

```
FROM denoland/deno

EXPOSE 8000

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

RUN deno cache main.ts

CMD ["run", "--allow-net", "--inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9229", "main.ts"]
```